# Can any one help on Installshield custom action settings?

Tags: installshield

i am new to installsheild deployment, i was tried many times, create custom action type--> New Powershell --Installed with Product.

then i specficed custom action to powershell script path- as ---Test.ps1.(browsing buttion)

this (Test.ps1) powershell script has path of my wsp.

like ----> **Add-SPSolution "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company Name\My Product Name\WorkflowProject1.wsp**"

then build and run the setup. but my wsp is not deployed.

i reset my iis for every installation---whenever i run my **installsheild setup.exe** of wsp.

can any one explain---**how to deploy wsp in instllsheild 2013.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have left out a step.  You need to specify the "Sequence" in which your CA needs to run; and where in that sequence.  Look farther down in the CA window on the right.  It is safer to use the 'Custom Action Wizard' (first entry in the drop-down list) instead of the way you did it.  That way you are reminded of all the things needed.